# Чи можна вживати прикметник "старий" біля іменників "дідусь", "бабуся"?

Tags: словосполучення, прикметники

Зустріла таку думку на [Уроках державної мови](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/282.htm):

> “Читаєш і чуєш: молода дівчина, старенький дідусь. А хіба це правильно?”
>   — Звичайно, ні. Не буває дівчини літнього віку. Ось і в 11-томному академічному Словнику української мови наголошується, що то ще неодружена особа. Тож треба казати і писати дівчина, не вдаючись до означень. Так само прикметник зайвий у висловах старенький дідусь, старенька бабуся. Правильно: дідусь, бабуся.

З частиною твердження можна погодитись, оскільки дівчина в [СУМ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=22578&page=770):

> ДІ́ВЧИ́НА, и, жін. **Молода** неодружена особа жіночої статі. Та й дівчина ж була [Олеся]! Велична, ..до всякого привітна й ласкава, і заговорить, і засміється, і пожартує (Марко Вовчок, I, 1955, 21); Три дівчини, студентки агрономи, йшли взимку по доріжці лісовій (Максим Рильський, III, 1961, 207);  * У порівняннях. Ось і рябина стоїть, мов дівчина заквітчала голову хмелем (Панас Мирний, I, 1954, 251);

А щодо дідуся з бабусею, не переконана, що це твердження правдиве. Оскільки ці слова мають кілька значень:

> ДІД, а, чол.
>
> 1. Батьків або материн батько. Родинне коло діда оточило, Сини та дочки, й молоді онуки (Леся Українка, I, 1951, 52).
> 2. Чоловік похилого віку. Був собі дід та баба. З давнього давна, у гаї над ставом, Удвох собі на хуторі жили (Тарас Шевченко, I, 1951, 311); Доки в баби поспіють книші, у діда не буде душі (Іван Кириленко, Вибр., 1960, 357);  * У порівняннях. Попід горою, яром, долом, Мов ті діди високочолі, Дуби з гетьманщини стоять (Тарас Шевченко, I, 1951, 41);

Тобто це не тільки чоловік похилого віку, а й чоловік, в якого з'явився онук чи онука. І такому чоловікові може бути 40 років, тоді часто називають молодим дідусем. Відповідно якщо дідусеві 70 років, кажуть старенький дідусь.
То ж чи справді слід уникати вживання прикметника "старий" біля іменників "дідусь", "бабуся"?

Comment: http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=22588&page=771
Є новий тлумачний СУМ-20, там замість цитат з Кириленка є цитати з Нечуя-Левицького. Жодних до вас претензій, просто ділюся інформацією.

Answer (score 1):

Визначення з СУМ-11

> [СТАРИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/staryj), а, е.
>
> **1.** *Який прожив багато років, який досяг старості*; протилежне молодий.
>
> //  у знач. ім. старий, рого, чол.; стара, рої, жін.; старе, рого,
>   сер., розм. *Людина, що прожила багато років*.
>
> //  у знач. ім. старі, рих, мн.: **а)** *те саме, що батьки*  **б)**
>   *подружжя, яке досягло старості.*
>
> //  *Уживається на позначення батьків на відміну від дітей у сполуч. з
>   ім'ям, прізвищем, прізвиськом і т. ін.*
>
> //  *Який давно народився, з'явився, почав рости (про тварин,
>   рослини).*
>
> //  ***Який має людина похилого віку.*** У ожинах хотів себе скрить
>   [дідусь]. Та дармаї тільки ноги старії Покровавив в колючім терні
>   (Іван Франко, XIII, 1954, 135); Важкі думи неначе каменем полягли на
>   її душу. З старих очей викотились дві сльози і потекли по зморщених
>   щоках (Нечуй-Левицький, VI, 1966, 408); Дід кивав своєю старою головою
>   (Максим Рильський, Бабине літо, 1967, 27); Ридає дід, цілує сина, з
>   старих підводиться колін (Володимир Сосюра, I, 1957, 354);

[Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9)

> **СТАРИ́Й** [**СТАР** *поет., фольк.*] (який прожив багато років), **ПОХИ́ЛИЙ**, **ПЕРЕСТАРІ́ЛИЙ, ПЕРЕСТА́РКУВАТИЙ** *розм.* (дуже старий або старіший, ніж треба для чого-небудь); **СТАРЕ́ЗНИЙ, ДРЕ́ВНІЙ**
>   *розм.,*
>
> *Любила [Маруся] в ті дні говорити зі статечними ґаздинями, **древніми** дідами* (Г. Хоткевич)

На мою думку, не слід уникати вживання прикметника "старий" щодо іменників "дід" та "баба". Адже Ви правильно підмітили: дідом/бабою можна стати і в 40, і в 20 років (мати онуків).